# Why can't .Net convert from short to int?

Tags: .net, int

One of my data types in SqlServer is `smallint` and this maps to `short` or `Int16` in .NET. I was using a simple for loop with i being an int and it told me it couldn't implicitly convert between the two?

I was just wondering why this isn't possible? Is it just to prevent you from using a larger number than a short can hold? It seems strange to me because I'm around 80% sure I've never had to convert an `int` to a `long`?

Sample:

```
public Int16 Test()
{
    int i = 2;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Sounds fishy, can you post code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: You won't need to convert an `int` to a `long` because a `long` is larger than an `int` in CLR types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An implicit from `short` to `int` should exist because you are going from narrow to wide, wide to narrow is not supported implicitly because of *potential* data loss. The compiler allows you to ignore this, but requests that you cast *explicitly* in these cases to state that you've understood the potential and that you are OK with it.

**Update:**

Your code is a narrowing cast and cannot be done implicitly. Fix:

```
public Int16 Test()
{
    int i = 2;
    return (Int16)i;
}
```

Although, to be facetious, in this particular case the compiler could theoretically know that no data loss will occur. For the other 99.99% of the time it cannot know this at compile time, thus only explicit casting is supported where data loss might occur.

This clearly places the onus on the developer such that when a runtime error occurs due to data loss, the developer would have had to consciously make that decision prior and has no legal standing to hurl expletives at the computer.

VB.NET appears to allow you to circumvent even this restriction using Option Strict:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e(v=vs.80).aspx

So I presume this is a C# specific design choice.

Comment: Just to piggyback what Adam has said here, going from a larger container to a smaller container guarantees a loss of data.  Explicitly casting it tells the compiler that you are aware of that fact and are doing it on purpose.

Comment: @DJQuimby Ta, amended my answer slightly.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I know how to fix it. The question was why

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth A fix would also be to just declare i as an Int16.

Comment: @danRhul I have answered that also, the fix is for clarity and other site visitors who may not know. And I know what alternative fixes there are.

Comment: @downvoter Difficult to learn from mistakes if all you do is a drive-by downvote.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a predefined implicit conversion from short to int, long,
>   float, double, or decimal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Implict conversions will only be carried out on non-narrowing conversions (to prevent loss of data).

Comment: We are talking about non-narrowing conversion (short -> int)

Comment: @JakubKonecki Actually we're talking about int -> short

Comment: Ha, if only the question was correct from the begining... ;-)

Comment: @JakubKonecki Well, the question implies both so you are half there :-)

Comment: @JakubKonecki Didn't change the question though

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what language you are using.

VB will convert without a problem by default as long as you dont overflow your Int16.
If you enable Option Strict you will have to do the conversion yourself:  `Convert.ToInt16(yourInt32)`

In c# you have to cast it:  `(Int16)yourInt32`